# Why do boost/etc do so much SFINAE on template member functions' argument types?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, sfinae

What is the rationale for selectively excising template member functions from class interfaces when the arguments do not satisfy various criteria, tested for with `enable_if` etc?  If the member function templates were left in, attempting to use them would fail, and it seems to me, with a more useful compiler error than 'substitution failure' in the more complex case?

If compilation fails either way, what is the argument in favor of these extremely strict SFINAE-based template member function requirements?

Answer (score 4):

Compiler errors 2-5 deep in template code have been found to be nearly impenetrable.  You get a spew of template noise.

SFINAE substitution failures usually list a template and say it doesn't work because some argument cannot be deduced, often with the trait that failed displayed.  Not perfect, but better than template spew.

What more, such templates can block other ones which are valid.

In addition, you can test if a given method exists and is valid at compile time if you use SFINAE-like techniques; you cannot if the body fails to compile.

Comment: Also could avoid ambiguities e.g. when initializing variants etc. (You almost said it with "can block other ones which are valid")

Answer (score 2):

Which error message do you find easier to understand. This one with SFINAE?

```
template <class C, class = decltype(begin(std::declval<C&>())[0])>
void sort_sfinae(C& c) {
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
}

main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
main.cpp:11:18: error: no matching function for call to 'sort_sfinae(std::__cxx11::list<int>&)'
     sort_sfinae(l);
                  ^
main.cpp:5:6: note: candidate: template<class C, class> void sort_sfinae(C&)
 void sort_sfinae(C& c) {
      ^
main.cpp:5:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
main.cpp:4:62: error: no match for 'operator[]' (operand types are 'std::__cxx11::list<int>::iterator {aka std::_List_iterator<int>}' and 'int')
 template <class C, class = decltype(begin(std::declval<C&>())[0])>
                                                              ^
```

---

Or this one without?

```
template <class C>
void sort_no_sfinae(C& c) {
    std::sort(c.begin(), c.end());
}

In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h: In instantiation of 'void std::__sort(_RandomAccessIterator, _RandomAccessIterator, _Compare) [with _RandomAccessIterator = std::_List_iterator<int>; _Compare = __gnu_cxx::__ops::_Iter_less_iter]':
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:4698:18:   required from 'void std::sort(_RAIter, _RAIter) [with _RAIter = std::_List_iterator<int>]'
main.cpp:6:14:   required from 'void sort_no_sfinae(C&) [with C = std::__cxx11::list<int>]'
main.cpp:11:21:   required from here
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1964:22: error: no match for 'operator-' (operand types are 'std::_List_iterator<int>' and 'std::_List_iterator<int>')
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
                      ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/list:60,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:328:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> typename std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>::difference_type std::operator-(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator-(const reverse_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:328:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1964:22: note:   'std::_List_iterator<int>' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
                      ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/list:60,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:380:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> decltype ((__y.base() - __x.base())) std::operator-(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator-(const reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:380:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1964:22: note:   'std::_List_iterator<int>' is not derived from 'const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>'
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
                      ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/list:60,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1138:5: note: candidate: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> decltype ((__x.base() - __y.base())) std::operator-(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
     operator-(const move_iterator<_IteratorL>& __x,
     ^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1138:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1964:22: note:   'std::_List_iterator<int>' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>'
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
                      ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algobase.h:67:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/list:60,
                 from main.cpp:1:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1145:5: note: candidate: template<class _Iterator> decltype ((__x.base() - __y.base())) std::operator-(const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>&)
     operator-(const move_iterator<_Iterator>& __x,
     ^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_iterator.h:1145:5: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/algorithm:62:0,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:1964:22: note:   'std::_List_iterator<int>' is not derived from 'const std::move_iterator<_Iterator>'
     std::__lg(__last - __first) * 2,
                      ^
In file included from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/vector:65:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/random.h:34,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/random:49,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_algo.h:66,
                 from /usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/algorithm:62,
                 from main.cpp:2:
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_bvector.h:208:3: note: candidate: std::ptrdiff_t std::operator-(const std::_Bit_iterator_base&, const std::_Bit_iterator_base&)
   operator-(const _Bit_iterator_base& __x, const _Bit_iterator_base& __y)
   ^
/usr/local/include/c++/5.3.0/bits/stl_bvector.h:208:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from 'std::_List_iterator<int>' to 'const std::_Bit_iterator_base&'
```

Comment: Point taken.  Will they be redundant if concepts are ever implemented?

Comment: @experquisite SFINAE is basically the best-we-can-do hack version of concepts. With concepts, the error would be [*even better*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3701.pdf).

Comment: @Barry It sort of depends. If I have two dozen overloads, maybe I'd prefer one spew of errors from the guts of the one overload I'm interested in, rather than two dozen messages that are mostly about overloads I don't care about.